# exp() function in Matlab yields different results that exp() in python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, exp

Basically, while translating code from Matlab to Python, I realised that there was a difference of the order of e-15 in my results.

Then I realised that all of this is caused by the `exp()` functions yielding different results ([exp() in Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html), [exp() in Python Math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), [exp() in Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html)). It seems like a small difference, but this slight difference accumulates over iterations and the final results end up exploding.

For instance, if you write `exp(2.34983545)` in both Python and Matlab, and export the result from Matlab to python (or viceversa), and compare it, you can see that it yields different results (again, order of e-15).

Please let me know if anyone has had this problem and if there is a way to fix it!

The simple code in matlab:

```
exp_result = exp(2.34983545)
save('exp_result.mat','exp_result')
```

The simple code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.io import loadmat

np_exp = np.exp(2.34983545)
math_exp = math.exp(2.34983545)

matlab_data = loadmat('exp_result.mat')
matlab_exp = matlab_data['exp_result']

print(np_exp - matlab_exp)
print(math_exp - matlab_exp)

#output yields -1.7763568394002505e-15
```

I would like to add that I have compared 500 million elements using the loadmat method, and the accuracy is pefrect for all results, except for the exp() functions.

I am aware of numerical impercisions due to floating point operations, but how can this be fixed in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I am aware of numerical impercisions due to floating point operations` then you know what the problem is. The way the internal `exp` algorithms handle floating point values must be subtly different between the two independent languages, you can't assume they will give the same result to a infinite precision

Comment: Moreover, the "fix" is to never use precise equality to assess whether the two floating point values are "equal", instead compare the absolute difference within some tolerance near machine precision

Comment: @Wolfie How does that "fix" of yours fix the issue (that "this slight difference accumulates over iterations and the final results end up exploding")?

Comment: Without a [mcve] of what the iterative process is, we can't suggest anything more. The code would have to be written in such a way that a difference that small does not have a large impact. If an algorithm is truly reliant on that precision (asking for trouble) then you would have to use something like [VPA in MATLAB](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)

Comment: Thank you @Wolfie for your comments. I'll end up seeing the MATLAB VPA to a higher degree of precision (quadruple maybe) and hence try to solve the problem. But it's simply a shame because all other stuff is working to the same exact precision (I'm speaking about sine, cosine, matrix multiplication, etc.).